# AJAX and jQuery search CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to do AJAX search for my application but I have some problems.

I have table posts with fields id, title, summary, content. I want to make posts search by title.

In my controller I load model posts and my index function look like this

```
function index()
        {

        $search=  $this->input->post('search');
        $query = $this->posts->search_posts($search);
        echo json_encode ($query);
        }
```

in my model posts.php I put this function

```
function search_posts($search){
                $this->db->select("id,title,summary,content");
                $whereCondition = array('title' =>$search);
                $this->db->where($whereCondition);
                $this->db->from('posts');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result();
        }
```

and my view look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?>">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.technicalkeeda.com/js/javascripts/plugin/json2.js"></script>

                <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                          $("#search").keyup(function(){
                                if($("#search").val().length>3){
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "post",
                                        url: "http://localhost/blogFinal/index.php/blog",
                                        cache: false,  
                                        dataType: 'json';                         
                                        data:'search='+$("#search").val(),
                                        success: function(response){
                                                $('#finalResult').html("");
                                                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                                                if(obj.length>0){
                                                        try{
                                                                var items=[];   
                                                                $.each(obj, function(i,val){                                                                                    
                                                                    items.push($('<li/>').text(val.title + " " + val.summary));
                                                                });     
                                                                $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                                                        }catch(e) {             
                                                                alert('Exception while request..');
                                                        }               
                                                }else{
                                                        $('#finalResult').html($('<li/>').text("No Data Found"));               
                                                }               

                                        },
                                        error: function(){                                              
                                                alert('Error while request..');
                                        }
                                });
                                }
                                return false;
                          });
                        });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="wrap">
                        <header>
                                <h1><?php echo anchor('','My Blog'); ?></h1>
                        </header>
                        <div id="container">
                                <div id="loginDiv"><?php echo anchor('admin/logout','Logout'); ?></div>
                                <hr/>
                                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
                                <ul id="finalResult"></ul>
                        </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"> </div>
```

I make this by following [tutorial](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql) but it doesn't work for me.

Can somebody help me please? Thanks!

Comment: can you get post['search'] in controller?did you check?

Comment: I haven't mention that I got output something like this [{"id":"1","title":"My First Post","summary":"This is my first post!!!!! ","content":"This is my very first post and you should know that.}]

Comment: @asef seferov I'm not sure I understand what to check? Sorry I'm new in CodeIgniter.

Comment: You don't mention what problem you're having. If you put a breakpoint in $('#finalResult').html("") , does it ever get there ? If not, check that the response from the PHP is indeed what you think it is by logging the output of json_encode ($query) before sending it back

Comment: remove JSON.parse(response) in your code, ajax alredy parse when you use dataType: 'json';

Comment: Amnon: if I put $('#finalResult').html("") I'v got the same result, nothing change.

Comment: asef seferov: if I remove JSON.parse(response) what to use in if statement below if(obj.length>0){ because var obj = JSON.parse(response)? Or to remove all if statement?